# warning: left-hand operand of comma has no effect in g++ compiler

Tags: c++, g++

```
int a, b, i=10, j=20; 
a = (i,j); 
b = i,j ;`
```

When I compile the above
program in linux (g++) I am getting warnings at line number 2:

> left-hand operand of comma has no effect)

and line number 3

> (right-hand operand of    comma    has no effect).

I do not understand what is wrong.

Comment: What value would you expect ``a`` to have? ``i`` or ``j``? Or both? ;)

Comment: I want to print both

Comment: @user2787274 *"I want to print both "* - well, `std::cout << i << ' ' << j << '\n';`, or if you want to save both in one variable and print them later, your could use a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair): `#include <utility> std::pair<int,int> a { i, j }; std::cout << a.first << " ' << a.second << '\n';`.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think this bit does?

```
 a = (i,j);
```

It's equivalent to:

```
a = j;
```

The compiler's just saying there's no point using the comma operator when the earlier terms have no side effects (i.e. evaluating `i` didn't "do" anything); given you've done something pointless, it assumes you did it by accident and is warning you to check....

That contrasts with something like this...

```
a = (++i, j);
```

...where there is a side effect of the evaluation of the first term: `i` is incremented.

Comment: b = i because comma has the least precedence of all operators - use parenthesis